# Unity blocked after changing Time region

Tags: unity

I reinstalled Windows then Installed Unity. Then I changed my timezone from US Pacific to Europe where I actually live. Unity got blocked: "Expired licence" even though I use the free version. https://forum.unity.com/threads/expired-license-on-free-version.90072/

If I change my timezone back to US Pacific Unity works (Took me 2 hours to figure out it was the timezone btw). I tried reinstalling Unity from scratch, didn't work. How can I change timezone back to Europe without locking up my Unity licence?

Comment: This looks like a bug to report to Unity's developers.

Comment: I'm using version 2017.3.1 and obviously I cannot upgrade while working on projects